# Percent Sign within JFormattedTextField appears spaced differently between Linux and Windows

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting

On Linux, the percent sign appears separated from the corresponding value within a `JFormattedTextField`. Like this: `123,0000000000 %`.

On the other hand, on Windows, it's displayed attached to the value: `123,0000000000%` (no space in between). Hence, double-clicking to only edit the value becomes a pain on Windows.

The locale is German.

Can I force Windows to put the percent sign separately, like Linux does?

```java
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class PercentSignSpacing extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private JFormattedTextField textField;
    private NumberFormat pFormat;

    public PercentSignSpacing() {
        pFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
        pFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(10);
        textField = new JFormattedTextField(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new NumberFormatter(pFormat),
                new NumberFormatter(pFormat), new NumberFormatter(pFormat)));
        textField.setValue(123.0 / 100);
        textField.setColumns(20);
        textField.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this);
        add(textField);
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            textField.setValue(((Number) textField.getValue()).doubleValue());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Percent");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                frame.add(new PercentSignSpacing());
                frame.add(new PercentSignSpacing());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect that your code shows "123,0000000000%" under Windows? I got a space character under Windows 10.